# Differentiability of a function from the plane to the line at the origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x,y) = (x^3 + y^3)^{1/3}$. I want to study the diffrentiability of $f$ at the origin. My claim is that it is not differentiable at the origin.

MY try:

To show this, suppose by contradiction that it is differentiable at the origin. Then, by definition, there exists a linear $T$ such that

$$ T(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{||h|| } =_{h = (x,y)}  \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{||h||} = \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{ (x^3+y^3)^{1/3}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}$$.

Notice, $T(1,0) = T(0,1) = 1$. But $T(1,1) = 2^{-1/6}$. Hence, $T$ cannot be linear. This is a contradiction, and hence $f$ cannot be differentiable at the origin.

Is this correct? Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your workout is incorrect.

Comment: can you explain why it is incorrect?

Comment: The definition of derivative : Let $f : R^n \rightarrow  R^m$. Then derivative of $f$ at the point $(x_1, \dots , x_n) \in R^n$ is a linear transformation $T$ from $R^n$ to $R^m$, satisfying the following : $$ f(x_1 + h_1, \dots , x_n + h_n) = f(x_1 , \dots, x_n) + T(h_1, \dots , h_n) + O(h^2),$$ where $O(h^2)$ accounts for the remainder/error term which is order of $h^2$.

Comment: That is you can take equality for $T$ in this case but that error term remains.

Comment: While we are at it: What is your definition of $t^{1/3}$ when $t\leq0\ $?

Comment: There should not be $(x,y)$ in the bracket after $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is more or less correct, but you might want to made that rigorous. Note that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if there is a linear map $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that

$$f(x, y) = f(0,0) + T(x, y) + o(\sqrt{x^2+ y^2})\ .$$

That is

$$(x^3 + y^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} = ax + by + o(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\ .$$

By putting $y=0$ and $x=0$, we have $a=b=1$. By setting $x=y$, we have

$$2^{\frac{1}{3}} x = 2 x + o(|x|)\ .$$

Divide by $x$ and take $x\to 0$, we have $2^{\frac{1}{3}} = 2$, which is impossible. This shows that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the function’s directional derivatives at the origin:

If $\mathbf u=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, then $$D_{\mathbf u}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h\cos \theta,h\sin \theta) - f(0,0)}{h}=(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)^{1/3}$$
But if $f$ is differentiable, then we must also have $D_\mathbf u=\nabla f\cdot \mathbf u=\cos \theta+\sin \theta$ at the origin (since $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=1$).